Create a class for user registration using Google email/password authentication
I am trying to create a class for adding a user to the Firebase firestore by using the Google email/password. I have the code as part of another screen but I want to pull it out and create a class. I'm not sure how I can do this.
I have tried to create a class but it is more complicated than I know how to do.
I want to pass the email and password to the class but I am not sure how to do that with what I have done.
I also use a snackbar to show if there are any errors creating the account but I don't know how I can include all of this in a class.
I am making a mess of this class. It works if I don't try to make a class out of it so maybe I should just leave it?
Here is the code:
class UserRegistration extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool showSpinner = false;
  bool registrationFail = false;
  String errorMessage = "";

  @override
  void register_user() {
    try {
        final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: widget.email, password: widget.password);
        if (newUser != null) {
          ref
              .read(usersNotifierProvider.notifier)
              .updateuserID(newUser.user!.uid);
          ref
              .read(usersNotifierProvider.notifier)
              .updateEmail(newUser.user!.email!);
          ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewUser(true);
          ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewCompany(true);

          /// Send the email verification
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const VerifyEmailScreen()));
        } else {
          setState(() {
            registrationFail = true;
          });
        }
        setState(() {
          showSpinner = false;
        });
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
        switch (error.code) {
          case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
          case "invalid-email":
            errorMessage = "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
            break;
          case "email-already-in-use":
            errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
            break;
          case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
          case "wrong-password":
            errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
            break;
          case "weak-password":
            errorMessage = "Weak password";
            break;
          case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
          case "user-not-found":
            errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
            break;
          case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
          case "user-disabled":
            errorMessage = "User with this email has been disabled.";
            break;
          case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
          case "too-many-requests":
            errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
            break;
          case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
          case "operation-not-allowed":
            errorMessage = "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
            break;
          default:
            errorMessage = "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
        }

        if (errorMessage != "") {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar((SnackBar(
            content: Center(
              child: Text(
                errorMessage,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
              ),
            ),
            behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
              left: 10,
              right: 10,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          )));
        }
      }
    }
}

Any help you can give me would be very much appreciated. Thanks

What isn't working about the code you shared? Is there an error message?

The code works where I have it in another class but I want to make it a class of it's own. I have tried to create a class but I don't know how to structure the class, I don't know all the dependencies I need for things like await, and I just basically don't know how to create this class. I am too new at this and I have searched the internet for an answer but everything is too basic to help me.

I get it, but that is rather hard to help with. There are dozens of steps to extracting that code, and we can't write a custom tutorial that covers those steps in your context. Well... we probably could, but it be really inefficient as that's gonna be a lot of work and really only helpful for you. Instead, I recommend taking each error you get in turn and trying to solve that. For example, to be able to use await in register_user, you will have to mark it with async. If you search for the error message you get now, you'll find dozens of questions that already cover that.

If you get stuck on one specific problem, you can post an individual question about that. But be sure to limit it to one specific, minimal problem. I recommend reading How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, which covers precisely how to create such an isolated repro.
